# why is flatMapConCat needed in this code?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

Here is the code where:
`userDao.getUsers` returns  `Flow<List<User>>` from Room database.
`userService.getUsers` returns `Flow<List<User>>` from a remote server.

```
    class MainViewModel(
    private val userService: UserService,
    private val userDao: UserDao
) : ViewModel() {

    var resultState by mutableStateOf<List<UserEntity>>(emptyList())
        private set

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            flow {
                emit(userService.getUsers())
            }.onEach { userList ->
                val userEntities =
                    userList.map { user ->
                        UserEntity(
                            user.id,
                            user.name, user.username, user.email
                        )
                    }
                userDao.insertUsers(userEntities)
            }.flatMapConcat {
                userDao.getUsers()
            }   .catch { emitAll(userDao.getUsers()) }
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .collect { list ->
                    resultState = list
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Below I modified the code by removing `flatMapConcat`. Why? you may ask. I think it does not concatinate anything so I deleted it. Now I have this code:

```
    class MainViewModel(
    private val userService: UserService,
    private val userDao: UserDao
) : ViewModel() {

    var resultState by mutableStateOf<List<UserEntity>>(emptyList())
        private set

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            flow {
                emit(userService.getUsers())
            }.onEach { userList ->
                val userEntities =
                    userList.map { user ->
                        UserEntity(
                            user.id,
                            user.name, user.username, user.email
                        )
                    }
                userDao.insertUsers(userEntities)
            }

// flatMapConcat is removed 

                userDao.getUsers()
               .catch { emitAll(userDao.getUsers()) }
                .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                .collect { list ->
                    resultState = list
                }
        }
    }
}
```

However, now resultState is not updated anymore. `flow` has filled the database with users. Now I call `userDao.getUsers`, which returns a `Flow`. I call `collect` to retrieve some data but will fail all the time. The problem may be that `userDao.getUsers` finishes before `flow` but these are just normal functions so they must execute sequentially. The database must be filled with some data when I call `userDao.getUsers`. That is the sequence of events that happen.
Could you please explain why the modified code does not work. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin flows are (usually) [cold](https://elizarov.medium.com/cold-flows-hot-channels-d74769805f9).

In your modified code, you have

```
flow {
    ...
}.onEach {
    ...
}
```

This simply **defined** a cold flow. That piece of code is not run at all.

The old code with `.flatMapConcat` has chained that flow with the `.collect`, which makes the flow run.

---

You are right that your code doesn't have anything to concatenate. The flow before `.flatMapConcat` has only one element.

Therefore you can simply write

```
val userEntities = userService.getUsers().map {
    ...
}
userDao.insertUsers(userEntities)

userDao.getUsers()
    .retry()
    .collect { list ->
    }
```

This code is slightly different from your old code. The retry mechanism doesn't catch exceptions from `userService.getUsers()`, I'll let you decide if that is important.

---

BTW I believe you don't need `.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)` as the `Flow`-returning methods of Room are already main safe.